# Forward-closure of `this` before calling `super(...)` (or: "the mind-bending story of WTF seriously")

Tags: typescript, closures, this, super

after some fiddling, I ended up writing this in TypeScript:

```js
 class B extends A{
     constructor() {
         const c = new C(() => this.method());
         super(c);
         c.someMethod(this);
     }
 }
```

And it works ...

*Let's set aside why I did this for a second (irrelevant to my question)*

My questions are :

- How in the world does it compile when I do things before the call to `super` ?!
- How can the line `const c = new C(() => this.method());` closure `this` when it is not yet defined ?

  - at least `this` should not be available or I'd rather have done `const c = new C(this.method);` but it did not compile, complaining that `this is not, yet, available`.

I am missing something there :/

Comment: What is the constructor for `C`?

Comment: How is that relevant ?

Comment: I'm curious as to whether the callback you pass is asynchronous or not

Comment: Sync/Async is not, in any way, a matter that impacts compilation, is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I think I see why this is bothering you.  The relevant issue in GitHub is [Microsoft/TypeScript#3311](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3311).  Let's see if I can answer these questions:

---

> - How in the world does it compile when I do things before the call to `super` ?!

Apparently it's because [you don't have member initializers](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3311#issuecomment-107651902).  From the linked issue:

> You can call `super` whenever you want if you don't have member initializers...
>
> If you look at how class member initializers are emitted, the reasoning for this becomes fairly clear. Member initializers are emitted after the super call (otherwise your derived-class initializers wouldn't properly overwrite base class initializations); by enforcing the super call to be the first thing the compiler can guarantee that there's exactly one (correct) place to emit those initializers.
>
> You move the super call to any position by removing member initializers -- this makes explicit what you expect the initialization order of each class member to be.

I think the language designers think there are some legitimate things someone could do before the `super` call (e.g., doing some computations to determine what to pass into the call to `super`), but that a few things are problematic: member initializers (which emit to JS as references to `this`), and explicit references to `this`.

---

> - at least this should not be available or I'd rather have done const `c = new C(this.method);` but it did not compile, complaining that `this is not, yet, available`

Right, you can't refer to the bare `this.method` before the call to `super` because `this` is not guaranteed to exist at that time.

---

> - How can the line `const c = new C(() => this.method());` closure `this` when it is not yet defined ?

My guess about the closure being accepted is that the reference to `this` must not be considered to come [lexically before](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6860) the `super` call.  This might or might not be a bug or design limitation in the compiler.  In your case, if the constructor of `C` doesn't actually call the function, then there's probably not an issue... the closure can potentially defer the dereferencing of `this.method` until after the subclass constructor is complete.  But since the constructor of `C` *might* call the function, the code could be unsafe.

If you feel strongly that this should give a compiler warning, you might want to raise an issue in GitHub and reference [Microsoft/TypeScript#3311](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3311) (you can't comment on that issue because it's been locked).

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: With those explanations this behaviour sound perfectly legit and your answer clarifies it very well. Thank you very much sir.